# How to create Layer using S3 bucket resource in AWS CDK (Python)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to migrate my boto3 code (Layer Creation) to CDK code in python, this is my boto3 code that works as expeceted:

```
# Create the Lambda Function Layer
LAYERNAME = 'paramiko_Package'
if not aws_utils.checklayerExist(session,LAYERNAME):
    boto_Lambda = session.client('lambda')
    Layer = boto_Lambda.publish_layer_version(
        LayerName=LAYERNAME,
        Description='This contains  the Python 3.8 libs for paramiko',
        Content={
                'S3Bucket': BUCKET_NAME, 
                'S3Key': 'aws_cdk/libs/packageParamiko.zip'
            },
        CompatibleRuntimes=['python3.8'],
        LicenseInfo='none'
        )
```

This works like a charm but i need to do it through the CDK and based on this link: [AWS CDK DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/README.html?highlight=layer)

CODE EX:

```
layer = lambda_.LayerVersion(stack, "MyLayer",
    code=lambda_.Code.from_asset(path.join(__dirname, "layer-code")),  <--- should be S3 resource
    compatible_runtimes=[lambda_.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X],
    license="Apache-2.0",
    description="A layer to test the L2 construct"
)
```

The problem is that the section for the code is pointing to an Asset and i need it to point to S3 bucket just like i do with boto3.

I believe i need to find a way to use this but i just cant figure it out: [AWS CDK DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Code.html?highlight=code%20bind_to_resource#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Code.bind_to_resource)

Tried this but failed:

```
    resource = core.CfnResource(self, 'ResourceS3Bucket', type='AWS::S3::Bucket', properties=[S3Key='aws_cdk/libs/packageParamiko.zip'])
    aws_lambda.Code.bind_to_resource(BUCKET_NAME,resource)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation i manage to create it like this:

```
   iBucket = aws_s3.Bucket.from_bucket_arn(self,'s3bucketmonitor',bucket_arn='arn:aws:s3:::12111111-us-west-4-cdk-bucket')
aws_lambda.S3Code(iBucket,key='aws_cdk/libs/packageParamiko.zip')

layer = aws_lambda.LayerVersion(self, "MyLayer",
                            layer_version_name="MyLayer",
                            code=aws_lambda.S3Code(iBucket,key='aws_cdk/libs/packageParamiko.zip'),
                            compatible_runtimes=[aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8],
                            license="none",
                            description="A layer to test the L2 construct"
                            )
```

This return an iLayerVersion object that you can just use directly on the lambda code.